# Navigation drawer menu with "SWRevealViewController" in iOS swift3

Tags: ios, navigation, swrevealviewcontroller

I implemented navigation drawer menu using `SWRevealViewController`. It was working fine as a menu drawer which is the navigation menu located as a `rootviewcontroller`, but in my app, only after the login page do I need to show the navigation menu in the home page.

In the home page, why is it not working?

Comment: Did you check that http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Comment: SWrevealcontroller is working fine, as if i create a new project and apply the follwing steps what appcode tutorial mentioned, But my question is, in my project, after launch screen i showed loginpage, after user login, it shows HomeViewcontroller page, in that homeviewcontroller page starting itself i need to add side menu.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check below image. I think you want something like this.[image]

2)If yes, then set the identifier sw_front like:
[image]

This will lead to home screen that comes after login.

3) then set the identifier sw_rear like:
[image]

This will lead to side bar menu.

4)Also write the following method in Appdelegate's **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let swRevealView: SWRevealViewController!
            swRevealView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("swRevealView") as! SWRevealViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = swRevealView
```

Comment: your explanation is very good, where i missed , i didnt write the code in appdelegate, now my app is working smoothly.